# Не срабатывает click() по элементу добавившемуся через append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```
$(".add_gr").click(function() {
$(".list").append('<div class="column">'+
    '<span class="span1">'+
        '<input id="ing" placeholder="№" style="width: 18px; margin: -1px -3px 0px -2px"> | </span>'+
    '<span class="span2">'+
        '<input id="nng" placeholder="Спец1альн1сть" style="width: 250px; margin:-1px 0px 0px 0px">'+
        '</span>'+
    '</span>'+
    '<span class="save_gl icon"><i class="icon fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Зберегти</span>'+
'</div>');});
```

все работает - все добавляет.

Теперь хочу словить событие `click()` по `save_gl`, но не работает.
Пробовал двумя способами:

1-й

```
$(".save_gl").click(function() {

//var id = $("#ing").attr('id');

alert("id");});
```

2-й

```
$(".column").on("click", ".save_gl", function() {
//var id = $("#ing").attr('id');
alert("qeqqe");});
```

Что не так господа ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть делегирования событий в том, что они привязываются к уже существующему элементу. Таким образом в ваших двух случаях

```
$(".save_gl").click(function()
```

привязываем событие к **уже присутствующим на странице** элементам с классом `save_gl`

```
$(".column").on("click", ".save_gl", function() {
```

привязываем событие к **уже присутствующим на странице** элементам с классом `column` и запускаем его, если оно всплыло от элемента с классом `save_gl`

Таким образом, любые добавленные элементы с указанными классами не будут отслеживать указанные события, так как вы добавляете `'<div class="column">'`

Решением может стать объявление данного события на элементе, который точно будет присутствовать, на *document* как в соседнем ответе, либо на контейнер куда вы добавляете, например

```
$(".list").on('click', ".column .save_gl", function(){...})
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ, буду знать !

Answer (score 6):

Второй вариант кажется более правильным.

Только привяжите к `$(document)`

```
$(document).on("click", ".save_gl", function() {
//var id = $("#ing").attr('id');
alert("qeqqe");
});
```

Comment: Благодарю. Работает !

Comment: рад... тогда закрываем вопрос - помечаем галочкой... повышаем рейтинг отвеченных вопросов в сообществе ;)

Comment: 2 минуты еще ) Ждем

Comment: @SlavikOkara... я, конечно, дико извиняюсь, но насчет закрытия вопроса - зеленую галочку поставьте. И лучше на ответ Grundy - он более развернутый... лучше для будущих посетителей... "Не корысти ради", как грится.. Именно для статистики

Comment: У Вас опечатка в слове *Только**п***

Comment: @Alex, спасибо, исправлено... В след. раз просто правьте смело ответ ;)

Comment: А вот не можем пока. Репутации после выхода из беты не хватает, и 1 символ функционал сайта поправить не дает