# Как удалить элемент созданый в append?

Tags: jquery

При клике на кнопку вставляется в **body** модальное окно ... в него пометил span.tragger так же созданный в append , но функция click не срабатывает ..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item = $("body");

  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    $(item).append("<div class='modal'><h3>Это окно приёма заявок</h3><span class='trigger'>x</span></div>")
  });
  $("span.trigger").on("click", function() {
    $(".modal").remove();
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.items {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 6px;
  width: 45%;
}

.item-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: ;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.item-flex h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.item-flex ul {
  padding: 6px;
}

.item-flex ul li {
  color: red;
}

.item-flex button {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:960px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .items {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.modal h3 {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .7);
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.modal span.trigger {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/ddd0000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/22aa99" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem2</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/cc0000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem3</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/222ff0" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem4</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/cc11cc" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem5</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

как закрыть **.modal** при **click** на **.trigger** которые созданы динамически?

Comment: вопрос разумеется не коммерческий ...чисто для самообазования

Comment: @Grundy это не дубликат ...и ни каого ajax там нету близко даже

Comment: важен принцип, там обновляется разметка и у тебя обновляется.

Comment: Тот же пример с `click`

Comment: @Grundy  тот вопрос ни каого сходства с моим не имеет ...

Comment: @Grundy  и что click только в ajax бывает ? аякс работает на сервере я же нет

Comment: Попробуй смысл ответа понять, а не буквальный код. Ты click навешиваешь на те элементы который уже есть в разметке (плагины инициализируются для тех элементов. которые уже есть разметки) Ты добавляешь новый элемент (там добавляется новый элемент) клик на новом элементе не работает (плагин для нового элемента не инициализирован)

Comment: Еще вариант дубликата: [Не срабатывает click() по элементу добавившемуся через append()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475348/186999)

Comment: @Grundy  а вот вторая ссылка .. согласен ..

Comment: Они все в итоге об одном и том же говорят.

Comment: @Grundy  второй да .. а первый нет ... там размыто .. но если спокойнее станет закрой , у тебя же есть такие права !

Comment: У меня права для [tag:javascript], а у тебя только [tag:jquery] :) ну и голос за закрытие я уже отдал.

Comment: @Grundy поддержу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте так:  `$("body").on("click",'span.trigger', function() {})`

Функция `on( events, selector, data, handler)`

**Events:**  один или несколько, разделённых пробелом типов событий .
**Selector:** селектор для фильтрации элементов, к которым привязано событие. Если селектор null или отсутствует, событие будет срабатывать дойдя до указанного селектора.
**Data:** данные, передаваемые в обработчик как event.data при запуске события.
**handler :** Функция обработчик события. Допускается false что означает функцию возвращающую return false.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item = $("body");

  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    $(item).append("<div class='modal'><h3>Это окно приёма заявок</h3><span class='trigger'>x</span></div>")
  });
  $("body").on("click",'span.trigger', function() {
    $(".modal").remove();
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.items {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 6px;
  width: 45%;
}

.item-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: ;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.item-flex h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.item-flex ul {
  padding: 6px;
}

.item-flex ul li {
  color: red;
}

.item-flex button {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

@media (max-width:960px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .items {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.modal h3 {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .7);
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.modal span.trigger {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/ddd0000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/22aa99" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem2</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/cc0000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem3</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/222ff0" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem4</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://place-hold.it/200x200/cc11cc" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item item-flex">
      <h3>lorem5</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>&#10004; item1</li>
        <li>&#10004; item2</li>
        <li>&#10004; item3</li>
        <li>&#10004; item4</li>
        <li>&#10004; item5</li>
      </ul>
      <button>lorem2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: повесить обработчик на другой элемент, не значит, что ты указываешь что-то конкретнее.

Comment: @Grundy  он верно же сделал ... вот тебе и дубликат вопроса

Comment: @Grundy отредактировал вступление, если это боле понятно ))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, собственно, его совет копия кода из вопроса дубликата в конце, поэтому да. Дубликат.

Comment: @Арсен, теперь стоит добавить **почему** нужно использовать так :)

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо ))